# Tagged logging in Rails 3.1.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3

I would like to know how the tagged logging can be implemented in Rails versions below 3.2. I have tried to override the logger.rb using a custom logger.

lib/custom_logger.rb

```
class CustomLogger < Rails::Rack::Logger

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    before_dispatch(env)
    @app.call(env)
  ensure
    after_dispatch(env)
  end

protected

  def before_dispatch(env)
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    path = request.filtered_path

    info "\n\nStarted #{request.request_method} \"#{path}\" " \
         "for #{request.ip} at #{Time.now.to_default_s}"
  end

  def after_dispatch(env)
    ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.flush_all!
  end
end
end
```

And added the line in environment.rb as

```
config.middleware.use CustomLogger
```

But however this only allows the **Started** lines to be customized. Is there any way to customize all server logs

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by tagged logging? In rails, has a specific meaning, you can follow the rails 4 implementation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89fab56597c335bb49887563b9a98386b5171574/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb#L59 it's documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TaggedLogging.html

Comment: I want to add some tags say request id with log messages

Comment: Do you want to erase server logs without **Started** lines?

Comment: No I want to add something like request id or remote ip with sever log